# Export table to csv in postgres function

Tags: postgresql

I use below command to export table to csv

```
COPY (
            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                table_name
            TO '/data/test/test.csv' WITH CSV DELIMITER ',' HEADER;
```

I used it in Postgres function but i cannot pass string to file path

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION backup (filePath CHARACTER VARYING)

    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE SQL
    AS $$
    -- Export data to csv
        COPY (
            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                table_name)
            TO filePath WITH CSV DELIMITER ',' HEADER;
       $$
```

err: `Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "filePath" LINE 16:    TO filePath WITH CSV DELIMITER ',' HEADER;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here [SQL Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html):

> SQL function arguments can only be used as data values, not as identifiers. Thus for example this is reasonable: ...

I'm going to say the `filePath` is being seen as an identifier. You will need to use `plpgsql` like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.backup(filepath character varying)
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
    BEGIN
    -- Export data to csv
        EXECUTE 'COPY ( SELECT * FROM table_name) TO '  || quote_literal(filePath) || ' WITH CSV DELIMITER '','' HEADER';
    RETURN;
    END;
$function$
```